# Clickable Maps In Container

Tags: codenameone

I have an Image (map of Africa). I want each countries to be clickable such that a new form is opened on tap. Is this possible with CN1?

I have checked the cn1libs portal and can't find any library that does this.

I thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create two maps. One would look like you want the map to look on the screen. The other would use a different color for every country.

- Use a pointer listener or `pointerReleased` on a focusable component to track user taps on the map so you'd have an X/Y coordinate.
- Use `getRGB()` to get the RGB colors of the pixels in the color map, then get the color at rgb[x + y * imageWidth]

This color represents the country that was picked and you can map to that using a switch statement.